# Laravel Application shows default apache and forbidden error

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have got a project to work on that is based on laravel. I have unzipped the folder in my 
`/home/testsite/public` folder and replaced the `httpd.conf` file which I have received.

Ran these two commands

```
chown -R username:group /home/testsite/public
chmod -R 777 /home/testsite/public/app/storage
```

But when I try to access localhost it shows default apache page, for other route url it shows 404 and it shows `Forbidden` when I try to access `localhost/server.php`

I have pasted my httpd.conf file here: http://pastebin.com/WLpFN7Sr

Comment: I think apache also needs access to /home/testsite directory, not just the public folder

Comment: I have all my laravel installation under /home/testsite/public directory. which also has a public directory insite it

Comment: Is the group you `chown`'d to the same group the apache user is in?

Comment: I am sorry , I am a beginner in linux, I just chown to tgugnani:tgugnani that is the only user I have other than root. Not sure which group apache user is in

Answer (score 0):

From your httpd.conf I see that your apache user is `apache` and its group is also `apache`. You can see that from these entries in the `httpd.conf`:

```
User apache
Group apache
```

Try this from within your project directory:

```
chown -R :apache .
```

I would also suggest that you *not* put virtual host or directory definitions inside of your `httpd.conf`.  Most distributions have a good place already for you to put them, where you can store a single vhost inside of a single file.  This makes it much easier when you want to enable one, disable another and general management becomes easier.

For instance, on ubuntu, I store all of my vhosts as separate files inside of:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

Comment: This did'nt helped, ran the command the restarted apache, still the same issue

Comment: what is the output whenever you run the `groups` command?  Also, what flavor of linux is this? Can you also double check to ensure that the group actually changed on the files?  You may need to run the chown with sudo

Comment: Running groups as root shows root and as tgugnani shows tgugnani. Its CentOS

Comment: Yes I did ran that command as root user.Also I double checked all folder and files are now owned by apache:apache

Comment: Hey @watcher thank you for the help, seems the problem was with selinux. Turning of selinux worked setenforce 0 . But not sure what selinux is

Comment: no prob, I was at a loss at what else could be the issue.  I'm not so good with CentOS :)